# Nginx proxy using domain as part of url path

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect, subdomain

I'd like to proxy `foo.domain.com` to the internal server `http://localhost:8080/foo`, the subdomain part is dynamic so `bar.domain.com` is also proxy to `http://localhost:8080/bar`.

I try this code up and running with **redirect**.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.domain\.com$;
    return 301 http://localhost:8080/$subdomain$request_uri;
}
```

However, I can't really find the solution using a **proxy**. I tried this but return 502.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.domain\.com$;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/$subdomain;
        # proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/$subdomain$request_uri; # this also not working
    }
}
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: is the domain always the same? afaik server_name does not use regex